# How to use nanoid without import

Tags: node.js, cryptography, nanoid

I am stuck with an issue,
I have to generate a 6 digit alphanumeric CODE which should be unique and for that i am using nanoid,
Now when i code this:

```
 const {nanoid} = require("nanoid");
 const ID = nanoid();
```

I got error:

```
    const {nanoid} = require("nanoid");
                 ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test\node_modules\nanoid\index.js from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test\server.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test\server.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test\server.js:1:18) {
  code: ←[32m'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'←[39m
}
```

if I code this:

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
const id = nanoid() //=> "V1StGXR8_Z5jdHi6B-myT"
```

i got error:

```
    (node:4636) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test\server.js:4
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Now I have tried changing package.json file

```
"type":"module"
```

but my project use babel and it will automatically convert import to require and as  result first error come again.

could you please tell me how to do nanoid with require'
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature, not a bug. See the changelog for details of the breaking change in version 4.0
https://github.com/ai/nanoid/issues/365

Comment: Yes, I got it
from version 4 they switched to es6 syntax completely and don't allow require()
If you want to use require() then you have to get low version (3.3.4) of nanoid